# How response pbf file in spring boot restful application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, content-type, protobuf-java

I have a pbf file like [this](https://d.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6/3/3/3.vector.pbf?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWhvY2V2YXIiLCJhIjoiY2pzbmg0Nmk5MGF5NzQzbzRnbDNoeHJrbiJ9.7_-_gL8ur7ZtEiNwRfCy7Q) and I want to response it with [spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) resfull application. Mapbox response server is as follow and I want to implement it with spring boot:

[image: Mapbox response headers]

Mapbox Content-Type is `application/x-protobuf`, How can I do it in spring boot restfull application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DownloadsController {

    @GetMapping("/getFile")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File("/home/sagara/Downloads/3.vector.pbf");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String fileName = file.getName();
        headers.add("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+ fileName);
        Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/x-protobuf"))
            .body(resource);
    }
}
```